# ubuntu 20.04 cinnamon font problem

Tags: fonts, cinnamon, 20.04, applet

I just upgraded ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 with cinnamon desktop environment. Then, it seems that fonts do not display properly in applets. Basically, I just see white boxes instead of letters, as in the attatched image.  For example, I tried using different fonts for my desktop and re-installing cinnamon desktop environment, but this font problem did not get resolved. How could I fix this font problem?

[image]

Comment: You could try to reset your cinnamon settings: https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/wiki/Backing-up-and-restoring-your-cinnamon-settings-(dconf) - Not sure how you may only reset your font config, but I guess that google knows.

Comment: Here's a thread about resetting the fonts only: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=292303

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Resetting the fonts only as in your second comment did not, but resetting my cinnamon settings as in your first comment resolved the font problem. Can you please post your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to reset your cinnamon settings:

**To backup** -
from a terminal, run: `dconf dump /org/cinnamon/ > backup_of_my_cinnamon_settings`

Save the `backup_of_my_cinnamon_settings` file somewhere for later.

***To reset to defaults:***
`dconf reset -f /org/cinnamon/`

**To restore all your settings:**
`dconf load /org/cinnamon/ < backup_of_my_cinnamon_settings`

Found here: https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/wiki/Backing-up-and-restoring-your-cinnamon-settings-(dconf)